# How do you permanently unprotect a workbook in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I saved a new excel file from a template that was password protected and now my file is password protected.  I know the password, so I can unprotect the tabs to edit what I need, but it's a hassle to do this every time.  When I save and exit the file, all the tabs become password protected again when I re-open it.

Is there any way to remove this password protect so I no longer have to unprotect every time I use the file?  I know you can "Allow users to edit ranges", which allows you to type in certain cells.  But this won't allow you to format any of those cells.

Answer (score 3):

**To remove protection from a worksheet**

1. On the Review tab, in the Changes group, click Unprotect Sheet.

> Note  The Protect Sheet option changes to Unprotect Sheet when a
>   worksheet is protected.

2. If prompted, type the password to unprotect the worksheet.
3. Then Save the file again.  Close Excel and open the sheet again and you shouldn't be asked for password.

Source: [Password Removal Excel 2010](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b8e38c76-6b69-4e6b-ad06-448497161e23/password-removal-excel-2010?forum=excel)

Answer (score 0):

to permanently unprotect a protected .xls sheet in MS Office 2010:

1. click on File tab
2. protected sheets are listed under Permissions section (under Info). Click on Unprotect next to the sheets that you want to unprotect and if prompted enter password.
3. click on Save As, and save as .xlsx [without VBa (Macros)]

Note: When saved as .xls, the sheets would be protected again.